# Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio 1.0 (Workspace)

Tags: eclipse, github, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So Android Studio has finally been released and I want to import my Eclipse Workspace into Android Studio, and after researching the differences in file structures, some sources say that

Workspace -> Projects

Projects -> Modules

That seemed simple enough, but then other sources say that modules in an Android Studio project are dependent on each other and should be able to work together (Like packages? But Android Studio has package folders too...), and my Eclipse projects are not dependent on each other, so I'm not sure what to do

Either I import my whole Eclipse Workspace from GitHub into Android Studio (Creating a module for each project)  Which makes the file structure look like [this](http://oi59.tinypic.com/11t8z74.jpg) (and I get the migrate project to Gradle error, not sure how to resolve that)

or

importing each project individually into Android Studio as an Android Studio Project (and then putting them into a master folder to be the 'Workspace')

Any suggestions to make this a less painful migration? Thanks

No feedback? :( If my question is unclear, please let me know..
An opinion would be nice.. I just don't want to mess up the workspace I created

Comment: I hope someone answers this real soon. Or do you know the answer already?

Comment: Sorry, I don't :( I just decided to import each project individually, it seemed like the more safer approach (yet time consuming...), I still have no idea what the purpose of a module is, since they are described like packages. I wish someone would answer who is familiar with Intellij, I like it, it's just the project structure is strange to me.

Comment: definitely strange and confusing. but according to what i understood, there is no "workspace" in studio, only projects. and modules are parts of the project, eg. the app itself, libraries, and i think for other module types. and you are focused to one project per windows, but you can open multiple windows.

Comment: yeah, I kind of created my own 'workspace' It's just a folder which contains all the Studio project folders, it works pretty well. Multiple windows? Sounds like it would consume quite a bit of memory :( But that's the approach I took, I hope I was of some help to you :)

Comment: haven't measured memory consumption yet, but yeah, sounds like it would consume more memory. but i guess the goal is to be more focused on a project? lol. anyway, thanks. and likewise. :)